# Google Cloud Storage access without providing credentials?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storage and have a few buckets that contain objects which are *not* shared publicly. Example in screenshot below. Yet I was able to retrieve file without supplying any service account keys or authentication tokens from a local server using NodeJS.

[image]

I can't access the files from browser via the url formats (which is good):
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/mygcstestbucket/o/20180221164035-user-IMG_0737.JPG
https://storage.googleapis.com/mygcstestbucket/20180221164035-user-IMG_0737.JPG

However, when I tried using retrieving the file from NodeJS without credentials, surprisingly it **could** download the file to disk. I checked process.env to make sure there were no GOOGLE_AUTHENTICATION_CREDENTIALS or any pem keys, and also even did a gcloud auth revoke --all on the command line just to make sure I was logged out, and still I was able to download the file. Does this mean that the files in my GCS bucket is not properly secured? Or I'm somehow authenticating myself with the GCS API in a way I'm not aware?

Any guidance or direction would be greatly appreciated!!

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = [projectId];

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId
});

// The name for the new bucket
const bucketName = 'mygcstestbucket';
var userBucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);

app.get('/getFile', function(req, res){
    let fileName = '20180221164035-user-IMG_0737.JPG';
    var file = userBucket.file(fileName);
    const options = {
        destination: `${__dirname}/temp/${fileName}`
    }
    file.download(options, function(err){
        if(err) return console.log('could not download due to error: ', err);
        console.log('File completed');
        res.json("File download completed");
    })
})
```

Comment: Could you include where you are running this code? E.g. is this from Cloud Shell, a computer you own, GCE, GAE etc?

Comment: My guess is that either this is running on GCE/container engine/app engine or GOOGLE_AUTHENTICATION_CREDENTIALS is in fact set.

Comment: I'm running from my local computer. I did a console log of all my process.env variables. There's no GOOGLE_AUTHENTICATION_CREDENTIALS set.. where can i check to see if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

Client Libraries use Application Default Credentials to authenticate Google APIs. So when you don't explicitly use a specific Service Account via  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` the library will use the Default Credentials. You can find more details on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#howtheywork).

Based on your sample, I'd assume the Application Default Credentials were used for fetching those files.

Lastly, you could always run `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (Or applicable to your OS) to confirm if you've pointed a service account's path to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create New Service Account in GCP for project and download the JSON file. Then set environment variable like following:

```
    $env:GCLOUD_PROJECT="YOUR PROJECT ID"
    $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="YOUR_PATH_TO_JSON_ON_LOCAL"
```